# Generating subtitles out of a pre-existing transcript via voice recognition

Tags: language-agnostic, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, transcription

Assuming I have the audio and a plaintext transcript of that audio, how can I use voice recognition to programmatically generate subtitles from the two?

This is very similar to something YouTube offers on its captions/subtitles page when editing a video.

What APIs are available to do this? What are some of the challenges with it?

I'm most fluent in Java/C# but this is language agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

This is called timestamping or alignment. [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) project project has a specific tool for that.  You can check it out from the subversion.

http://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cmusphinx/branches/long-audio-aligner/

For some information on usage please see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/?s=long+audio+aligner